# Can I swap Ctrl and Alt keys in xubuntu Terminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I run Ubuntu 22.04 XFCE as a VM (UTM) under macOS Ventura on a MBP M1 2022. It runs flawlessly, but within the VM I have to use the 'Option' key as Command/Alt and the 'Command/Alt' as Ctrl key. So far, so good, so Cmd+tab switches between Ubuntu in general and macOS apps and Option+Tab within the VM switches between Ubuntu apps.

But in a Ubuntu terminal I want to retain Ctrl for Ctrl and cmd/alt for Alt. How can I accomplish this swap for only a single app within Ubuntu ?

Comment: To be clear you want to use custom key assignments for only 1 unnamed app?

Comment: yes, a single app called Terminal, the standard xfce terminal.

Comment: Please update the question with edit to add this very important info.